# How to generate different text within an inline SVG according to a variable's value?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to generate  dynamically a svg according to an outside variable's value,

For example if the html page variable **lang** is set to "eng",
the text "Circle" will get presented otherwise the text with the corresponding language will be presented.

```
<svg height="300" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
    <text x = "50" y="150">Circle</text>
</svg>
```

Any suggestion how to do it?

Thank you all!!

Comment: You can use the [switch element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch)

Answer (score 1):

SVG is XML, so use [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) to transform one XML into another. XSLT may use several "external" documents storing, for example, dictionary data, labels, translations, etc.